# Is this the right approach to unit test a console app?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application

In my very first console app, I have everything running in one method.
But to unit test this would I basically need to add specific methods for certain console interactions and then add a return value to each method? Thus allowing me to validate the return values of said methods? Do these methods all need to have input arguments for my tests to work? Or can they function with just return values?

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

     namespace CalculatorApp
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Declare my and th

en initialize to zero.
            float num1 = 0; float num2 = 0;

        // Display title as the C# console calculator app.

        Console.WriteLine("Console Calculator in C#\r");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------\n");

        // Ask the user to type the first number.
        //Console.WriteLine("Type a number, and then press Enter");


        Console.WriteLine("Type a number, and then press Enter");
        bool Valid = false;
        bool Valid2 = false;
        float Number;
        while (Valid == false)
        {
            string Input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!float.TryParse(Input, out Number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer, please try again.");
            }
            else
            {
                Valid = true;
                num1 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(Input);
            }
        }

        // Ask the user to type the second number.
        Console.WriteLine("Type another number, and then press Enter");
        while (Valid2 == false)
        {
            string Input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!float.TryParse(Input2, out Number))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not an integer, please try again.");

            }
            else
            {
                Valid2 = true;
                num2 = (float)Convert.ToDecimal(Input2);
            }
        }

        // Ask the user to choose an option.
        Console.WriteLine("Choose an option from the following list:");
        Console.WriteLine("\ta - Add");
        Console.WriteLine("\ts - Subtract");
        Console.WriteLine("\tm - Multiply");
        Console.WriteLine("\td - Divide");
        Console.Write("Your option? ");
        bool isOperatorValid;
        do
        {
            isOperatorValid = true;
            switch (Console.ReadLine())
            {
                case "a":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} + {num2} = " + (num1 + num2));
                    break;
                case "s":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} - {num2} = " + (num1 - num2));
                    break;
                case "m":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} * {num2} = " + (num1 * num2));
                    break;
                case "d":
                    Console.WriteLine($"Your result: {num1} / {num2} = " + (num1 / num2));
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input please try again");
                    isOperatorValid = false;
                    break;
            }
        } while (!isOperatorValid);

        // Wait for the user to respond before closing.
        Console.Write("Press any key to close the Calculator console app...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I think that this is too broad question for StackOverflow. Maybe try on other parts of StackExchange like CodeReview?

Comment: Your code will be more readable, testable, maintainable and flexible if you would divide it to several functions.

Comment: Think about what actions the program performs that you would want to test. These would need to be extracted into functions such that you can provide test inputs and validate the resulting outputs. You don't need to test the Console (it's not your code), so you would want any Console interaction separate to those testable functions.

Comment: Normally people split logic into smaller classes and then unit test cases can be written against them. Find a typical TDD book and then you can learn that. Nobody tests a whole console application and call that unit testing (but if you insist you can, as `Process` class allows you to capture input/output).

Comment: You won't want to write or read from the console in the tests; user input will be "mocked" in the test. So, you'll need to move the operations to a class that just returns the result; that's what you'll test.

Answer (score 0):

This code is not testable, you have a lot of code inside the main class. Try to refactor your code, divide the code to other class with methods, it is the right way to unit test. It is a big subject very difficult to explain in one thread.

I create a guide to the basics of unit testing using console app, you could see the article [here](https://codefromstars.com/write-your-first-unit-test-in-c-using-nunit/)

I hope it could help you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another more modular way to write a console program would be to do something like below.  This has the advantage of moving the main processing out of the main() method and being able to keep the application more organized.

What this does it to create an instance of "Program", then call a public method named "Run()."  The "Run()" method will have access to all the private methods of the class "Program." This is a much cleaner approach. Otherwise the main() would not be able to call other methods in the class unless they were all declared as static.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run();

        Console.WriteLine("Program ran.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // call a private method
        Method1();

        // call a private method with param
        Method2("some string");
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    private void Method2(string s)
    {
        // do some stuff
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good start, but it doesn't help with the question because you should never test private methods.

Comment: You should test all your methods in one way or another.  Creating well defined single purpose classes and methods is the key to good programming practices.

Answer (score 0):

I would ideally like to see this code broken into smaller methods. Doing this will let you unit test the code in true sense.

Also if you are new to OOP concepts, I recommend reading a bit on SOLID principles. Reading these will give you a better sense of refactoring code too.